LWC Custom Lookup Component with 'Create New Record' Feature. Is there a way to get newly created recordId in LWC?
I've created a custom lookup component in Lightning Web Components (LWC) and added a feature to create a new record using the navigation mixin. I want to retrieve the record ID after the record creation is successful and use it in my LWC. Is there a way to handle this feature? Any guidance or code examples?
below is the my current implementation.
import { LightningElement, api,wire } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
export default class CustomLookupForm extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

newRecordOptions = [
    { value: 'Property__c', label: 'New Property' }
];
handleNewRecordClick(event) {
        const objectApiName = event.currentTarget.dataset.sobject; //Property__c
        const selection = this.newRecordOptions.find((option) => option.value === objectApiName);

        const preNavigateCallback = selection.preNavigateCallback
            ? selection.preNavigateCallback
            : () => Promise.resolve();
        preNavigateCallback(selection).then(() => {
            this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
                type: 'standard__objectPage',
                attributes: {
                    objectApiName,
                    actionName: 'new'
                },
                state: {
                    recordTypeId: this.recordTypeId,
                    defaultFieldValues: selection.defaults
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

